# Android studio manifest issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

My android studio seems to be not detecting AndroidManifest.xml file. When I try to run the app, configuration says that `Default Activity not found`, but in my manifest there is `activity` tag with necessary `intent-filter`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.ACTION.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

AndroidManifest.xml is located at `app/src/main` where it was initially created. Cleaning build, rebuilding, invalidating caches / restart does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names are case sensitive. Use:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

If that still doesn't work try to provide the full path to your activity e.g.:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.package.ui.MainActivity">
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. That action name was generated by autocomplete, so I didn't think to try to change it to lowercase. Will accept your anser in 7 mins